# How to make a LabVIEW knob/dial with a custom needle?

Tags: labview

I want to customize a knob/dial such that its needle would be perpendicular to the default orientation:

[image]

When customizing LabVIEW controls it is possible to import custom images, but in the case of a knob/dial, where the animation involves rotation, simply importing a custom image doesn't work: the imported image does not rotate at all.

How can I make a custom knob/dial with a different needle?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, this is not possible outside of some transparent-background magic. Even then, I don't think it will rotate as you expect. Apparently there are chart "lines" that can be customized and will rotate, but I couldn't make it work.

If this is purely for display, then I think the best way forward is to add a 2nd needle and create an x-control of sorts. If your input ranges from -90 to 90, make 2 needles and set their respective values to be +/-90 from the input and pass to the "xcontrol" (or strict type def if you don't want to mess with an Xcontrol, which I don't blame you).

This is nice because you can also color the 2 needles differently, to give a directional indicator. You could also add a 3rd needle that points in the true direction of the data input. Only issue is the need to have the data range of the indicator go to +/-180 to allow the needle to fully rotate and not stop at +/-90. I'm sure it can be hidden.

The use of arbitrary spaced markers allows this. Observe:
[image: Input @ 45]

[image: VI Snippet]

EDIT: Fixed messed up image